# Are higher branches of mathematics used in sub-fields of chemistry?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

I'm wondering is there any branches of Chemistry that make use of manifolds, Riemann geometry, tensors etc. So far I have not come across anything but hoped that the wider community would know of something?

Forgive me if this is too vague a question but I'm just looking for some topics I can research myself.

Comment: How many chemist you think know differential geometry? So, unless you try to explain what the hell is manifold and all other stuff you mentioned, your question is *very* unlikely to be answered.

Comment: The only thing I could come up by reading the Wikipedia article on manifold, is that potential energy surfaces do have some topological properties, thus, there should be some use of differential geometry for analysis of potential energy surfaces. Then I just googled and found something, say, http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-94-009-2313-3_3 amongst many other papers.

Comment: The author of the paper linked above also wrote a book with an interesting title "Shape in Chemistry: An Introduction to Molecular Shape and Topology" http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471187410.html

Comment: Aha, there is the so-called chemical topology. There is even a short article in Wiki about it (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology_%28chemistry%29) and some books with exactly this title (http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9789056991746).

Comment: And I hope, the information above is relevant, since I have no idea what these papers and books are about. :D

Comment: Thank you very much Wildcat. After all the internet searching I have done (and trust me it is extensive) I haven't come across either of the books you kindly linked! Thanks once again :D

Comment: Check out the book "When Topology Meets Chemistry" by Erica Flapan. In the light of new research on topologically interesting molecules (including molecular machines), the field is very interesting and relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- We use tensors in my research lab to analyze solid state NMR.
- In my research laboratory we use manifolds all the time for stimulating annealing calculations.

---

There are several research groups in physical chemistry which utilize what you are describing, but it will never be an undergraduate topic. One particular group that comes to mind that uses this sort of stuff a lot is the Hirata group at the University of Illinois. They actually made a piece of software called the Tensor Contraction Engine. http://www.scs.illinois.edu/~sohirata/software.html

Comment: Also tensors in EPR and solution state paramagnetic NMR